# Wiring on my receptacle

Tags: wiring, receptacle

So I'm confused with my receptacle. The bottom outlet didn't work so I went to replace it and upgrade to a GFCI. When taking off the old one it has a white neutral and a red and black on the hot side I put the wires exactly how it was on my old one but didn't work until I broke the tabs off the sides but still only the top outlet works. Why? Also this outlet is on a dual 15breaker.

Comment: Please show us a picture of this new GFCI receptacle from which you "broke off the tabs". To the best of my knowledge, GFCIs don't have tabs to be broken off - you cannot have the two individual outlets separated from each other. Also, they require the proper wiring to actually work as expected, and it's _highly_ likely you've got it wrong - it's easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

> I broke the tabs off the sides

This won't work with only 3 wires. You'll have to replace the receptacle again or create a double pigtail for the white side.  Also note, you can't use a double pigtail on a GFCI outlet.  These usually don't include tabs, so I'm not sure what kind of outlet you have without more information.

> dual 15breaker

This means the red wire is either connected to a switch or a different circuit.  Unless you're trying to create two separate outlets here, the red wire should be disconnected, and the receptacle tabs should be intact.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a switch that you are unaware of that is controlling the bottom outlet via (probably) the red wire. This used to be fairly common for rooms that were lit by table lamps rather than wall or ceiling fixtures.

In this case the receptacle would have had the tab broken on the hot side but not on the neutral side. On the hot side one receptacle would have a line hot (usually a black wire probably on the upper one) and one receptacle (of the pair) would have the switched hot from the wall switch.

Comment: The edits were correct but inappropriate. Write your own answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure this answer would be appropriate as it looked incomplete.  The question mentioned broken tabs (plural) and two circuits.  It sounded like turning the switch on wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: @robertchapin: Feel free to post your own answer addressing those issues, and /or to downvote mine if you think it does more harm than good. But at first glance it sounds like the classic setup if one switched and one unswitched socket per pair, with red probably being the switched hot if common US conventions were used. Yes, they might share neutral if they're split off the same feed ... or might not, if they weren't.